# How to install Intel HD 4000 grapics driver

Tags: ati

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP laptop with AMD amd Intel graphics card. I want use only Intel card, but there isn't drivers in option (picture).

[image]

Should I just install drivers from this page? https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Here seems to be the latest linux driver for hybrids like yours (according to google) - a

new beta for Linux just went out ( have you already been here ? ) :

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

(addition of 22nd July 2013 - because of newer news):

You have chosen the tag resp. the category 'ATI' for this thread ?

There is a new video since today as tutorial :

https://video.linux.com/videos/installing-official-linux-ati-drivers-from-amds-website

Comment: @BHOY40 here is since today a new video for your problem - you have ATI - right ?!